# split top three rows of pandas into three separate columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
    clientid    date    generatedTime   feature featurePercentage
0   12345   2022-11-18 00:00:00 2022-11-23 08:58:09 timely_log  1.0
1   12345   2022-11-19 00:00:00 2022-11-24 08:55:46 red 0.822815
2   12345   2022-11-19 00:00:00 2022-11-24 08:55:46 timely_log  0.177185
```

I need to group this dataframe by `clientid` and `date`, and then split the `feature` and `featurePercentage` values into separate columns, such that, the highest value of `featurePercentage` is added into new column called `First` and the corresponding value in `feature` column is added to column `First_feature`, similarly second highest value is added to column `Second` and corresponding `feature` value is added to `Second_feature` and likewise till top three values. Such that the output looks something like this

```
    clientid    date    generatedTime   First_feature   First    Second_feature    Second    Third_feature    Third
0   12345   2022-11-18 00:00:00 2022-11-23 08:58:09 timely_log  1.0    None    None    None    None
1   12345   2022-11-19 00:00:00 2022-11-24 08:55:46 red 0.822815    timely_log    0.177185    None    None
```

Comment: For each `date` is same `generatedTime` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#sorting featurePercentage descending per clientid and date
df = df.sort_values(['clientid','date','featurePercentage'], ascending=[True, True, False])

#create counter column
df['g'] = df.groupby(['clientid','date','generatedTime']).cumcount()

#filter top 3 rows per groups
df = df[df['g'].lt(3)]

#expected Multiindex
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['feature','featurePercentage'], range(3)])

#reshape by pivot and add missing values by MultiIndex
df = (df.pivot(index=['clientid','date','generatedTime'], columns='g')
        .reindex(mux, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1, level=1))

#mapping new columns names
d = {0:'First', 1: 'Second', 2: 'Third'}
df.columns = [d[b] if a=='feature' else f'{d[b]}_feature' for a, b in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   clientid                 date        generatedTime       First  \
0     12345  2022-11-18 00:00:00  2022-11-23 08:58:09  timely_log   
1     12345  2022-11-19 00:00:00  2022-11-24 08:55:46         red   

   First_feature      Second  Second_feature  Third  Third_feature  
0       1.000000         NaN             NaN    NaN            NaN  
1       0.822815  timely_log        0.177185    NaN            NaN
```

Solution for generate N new columns:

```
import inflect
p = inflect.engine()

N = 4

df = df.sort_values(['clientid','date','featurePercentage'], ascending=[True, True, False])
df['g'] = df.groupby(['clientid','date','generatedTime']).cumcount()

df = df[df['g'].lt(N)]

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['feature','featurePercentage'], range(N)])

df = (df.pivot(index=['clientid','date','generatedTime'], columns='g')
        .reindex(mux, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1, level=1))


df.columns = [p.number_to_words(p.ordinal(i+1)) .capitalize()
              if a=='feature'
              else f'{p.number_to_words(p.ordinal(i+1))}_feature'.capitalize() 
              for a, i in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   clientid                 date        generatedTime       First  \
0     12345  2022-11-18 00:00:00  2022-11-23 08:58:09  timely_log   
1     12345  2022-11-19 00:00:00  2022-11-24 08:55:46         red   

   First_feature      Second  Second_feature  Third  Third_feature  Fourth  \
0       1.000000         NaN             NaN    NaN            NaN     NaN   
1       0.822815  timely_log        0.177185    NaN            NaN     NaN   

   Fourth_feature  
0             NaN  
1             NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'clientid': [12345, 12345, 12345], 
                   'date': ['2022-11-18', '2022-11-19', '2022-11-19'], 
                   'generatedTime': ['2022-11-23 08:58:09', '2022-11-24 08:55:46', '2022-11-24 08:55:46'], 
                   'feature': ['timely_log', 'red', 'timely_log'], 
                   'featurePercentage': [1.0, 0.822815, 0.177185]})

def exx(group):
    sorted_group = group.sort_values(by='featurePercentage', ascending=False)
    result = {}
    result['First_feature'] = sorted_group['feature'].iloc[0] if len(sorted_group) > 0 else None
    result['First'] = sorted_group['featurePercentage'].iloc[0] if len(sorted_group) > 0 else None
    result['Second_feature'] = sorted_group['feature'].iloc[1] if len(sorted_group) > 1 else None
    result['Second'] = sorted_group['featurePercentage'].iloc[1] if len(sorted_group) > 1 else None
    result['Third_feature'] = sorted_group['feature'].iloc[2] if len(sorted_group) > 2 else None
    result['Third'] = sorted_group['featurePercentage'].iloc[2] if len(sorted_group) > 2 else None
    return pd.Series(result)

df = df.groupby(['clientid', 'date']).apply(exx).reset_index()
```